# Wireless icon not showing in the panel

Tags: 14.04, wireless, icons, panel

I just installed the Ubuntu 14.04 and I cant see wireless icon in the panel or any settings related to the wireless icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to list the interfaces,

```
sudo iwconfig
```

Please check whether you have installed wireless adapter

To check what drivers your wireless adapter is currently using, you may run the following command:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

lshw lists information on your hardware

-C network filters the output to only show the network class.

In the output, look for the entry with description: **Wireless interface and the driver**.

Alternatively, you can use the command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
```

lspci lists information on your PCI connected cards

-nnk instructs lspci to output more information about these cards (including the driver being used)

| pipes the output to the next command

grep 0280 filters the output to show lines containing 0280, which is the PCI class code for wireless PCI controllers in Ubuntu.

-A2 shows two more lines of information.

**If no driver is installed please follow the below link install Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA driver**

1) Depending on your system download 32 or 64 bit package
from http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

2) Go to a terminal to the dir with package.

3) tar -xvzf hybrid-portsrc-.tar.gz
Replace version with one you have

4) Install kernel headers (eg. in fedora “yum install kernel-headers”)

5) make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`

if There were no errors

6) Unload Modules from memory
rmmod ndiswrapper b43 ssb bcm43xx b43legacy

7) For WPA
modprobe ieee80211_crypt_tkip

8)Check if Compiled Module is working
insmod wl.ko

Now Probably a new interface will be there for wireless (wlan0 or eth-1)
To check it run
iwconfig
iwlist scanning

AND YES !! ITS Working !!!!!

B)Making it load on boot

1)cp wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname-r`/kernel/net/wireless/

2)depmod -a

3)rmmod wl

4)modprobe wl

5)Add following Lines to /etc/rc.local (in openSuse /etc/rc/rc.d/boot.local)

Once it is done check whether you can able to see wireless icon.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you believe he has a Broadcom device?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you are asking me to install the wireless driver again?
Because right now I just have issue with no wireless icon in the ubuntu panel although i can connect to wireless from settings> Network. 

Please let me know if there is any possible way to get the wireless icon in the panel so that i have not to go in the settings always for a connection. 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the driver manager and check if your wireless driver is enabled or not. This obviously depends on your network card, but that's the way I always set up my wireless connection.

Comment: But internet is working fine right now, the issue is just that I cant see any icon in the ubuntu panel. 
For now if I have to connect from a connection then i can do this from the settings > network. And there i can see all the available connections.